# How to get Jumbotrons not to touch vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, my images are touching vertically and I would like some spacing between them. I recently figured out how to avoid them touching horizontally with `Margin: 0 auto;`, but this left the images still touching vertically. I'd imagine it's an easy fix. Any suggestions for me?

HTML:

```
<div class="four">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">→</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">→</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">→</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">→</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.four .jumbotron
{ background: url("http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-zsusy2wy/products/2030/images/2051/IMG_0008_1__60351__59072.1453225152.330.385.jpg?c=2") no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
min-width: 220px;
max-width:250px;
min-height:260px;
max-height:300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: have you tried playing with the margin at all: `margin: 1em auto`

Answer (score 0):

In CSS their are multiple ways to determine a margin on each side of an element. Lets bring to example first that a margin can be written like so `margin: 5px 4px 7px 10px;` meaning top right bottom left `margin: {TOP} {RIGHT} {BOTTOM} {LEFT}`. You may also take away each number individually, to share values with it's opposite.

When removing each individual number, the removed "side" will share values with it's opposite (top:bottom,left:right). For example `margin: 5px 4px 4x`, would mean the top = 5px, right = 4px, bottom = 4px, left = 4px. Another example would be when removing all but one, for example: `margin: 10px`. Which would mean top = 10px, right = 10px, bottom = 10px, left = 10px.

Now when you add an `auto` in place of the 2nd number, for example `margin: 10px auto`. Which would now make the left and right side and automatic width, which will allow you to center items horizontally.

With your case you're looking to place a margin on the right bottom and left.

Answer: **`margin: 0px 10px 10px`**.